# Difference between different assignment in generics

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between

```
 List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: did you see the compiler warning for `List list ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing:

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you are not telling the compiler what kind of List it is. 
This would allow someone to compile this code:

```
String a =    (String)list.get(0);
```

which is clearly wrong and would cause you exception, because you can add anything in the list, so the compiler is not sure if list.get(0) is really an Integer.

Now with this way you are telling the compiler that this list will only accept and hold integers or Integer subclasses (in case it could be subclassed).

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

so this wouldn't compile:

```
String b = (String)list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, when you do `list.get(i)`, it will return an `Object`. In the second case, it will return an `Integer`. Think of `List<Integer>` as a more specific type of `List` (kind of like a subclass in OOP).

Comment: To be specific: it will return something which is `instanceof Object`  It might be an `Integer`.  It might be a `Giraffe`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you don't get any of the benefits of type safety offered by generics when you're using the first declaration -- it's pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Ernest's answer (which is accurate), here are some differences of usage:

```
List untypedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> typedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// What using the untyped list looks like
for (Object element : untypedList) { // The best we can do is get an Object
    Integer i = (Integer)element; // "no-value" code
    // do something with i
}
// or, cast to a typed list
for (Integer i : (List<Integer>)untypedList) { // ugly cast
    // do something with i
}

// But with a typed list, things are neater (less code = good)
for (Integer i : typedList) {
    // do something with i
}
```